# Which "elements", when added, will create a field extension to a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

If I am originally working with $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, with $n$ prime, and if I add both the values $\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $\left( \sqrt[3]{x} \right)^2$, will this create a field with $n^3$ elements?

What if I add $\sqrt[2]{x}$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}$ to the field $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$?  How many elements can I get out of this field, assuming that it's a field?

I'm essentially trying to find a field that has an element of multiplicative order $n^3-1$ by adjoining elements to the field $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$.  The real problem is that I don't want to use $\mathbb{F[y]}/p(y)$ for some polynomial in $y$ - in other words, I don't want to factor any polynomials to find this field.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is only a field if $n$ is a prime. For some values of $n$ and $x$, $x$ may *already* have a cubic root, so “adding” the values won’t do anything... Similarly with adding square roots. Some elements may have sixth roots already, meaning that adding a square and a cubic root doesn’t do anything. For instance, what if $x=0$?

Comment: The proper term is "adjoining" elements to a field.

Comment: A very easy way to construct a ring with $n^3$ elements is to take a ring $R$ with $n$ elements and look at $R\times R\times R$. Of course, that ring may not have other properties that you want....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  I believe that I'm trying to adjoin elements so that I can get an element with a larger multiplicative order.  However, I'm trying to avoid the operation of finding a reducible polynomial to do this.  I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: What you have is, sorry, a bit of a mess. First, you talk about fields when you don’t know if you have fields; you talk about $x$ without telling us if $x$ is an element of your ring, or an indeterminate; and you don’t tell us what you want other than saying you want a ring of a given order (burying extra desires in the comments doesn’t make things clearer, it makes them worse, forcing people to dig through comments to figure out what it is you *really* want). So you need to clean it up before you can get a reasonable answer.

Comment: Still a bit of a mess. Is $n$ supposed to be a prime? Then use $p$, not $n$, and say it is a prime. Also, $\mathbb{F}/p(x)$ does not make sense. Do you mean $\mathbb{F}[x]/p(x)$? So is $x$ an indeterminate all along, or is $x$ an element of $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: Note: a field with $p^3$ elements will **never** have an element with multiplicative order $p^3$. The multiplicative order of an element in a field of order $p^k$ is at most $p^k-1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  Yes, I want an element with order $n^3-1$

Comment: Then why do you say in your post you want an element of multiplicative order $n^3$? And why use $n$ instead of $p$ to denote a prime? While notationally they are equivalent, one requires the reader to do more work than the other. And why are you still mysterious about the nature of $x$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  Sorry, I meant order $n^3-1$, and I'm not trying to be that mysterious.  I'm just working on an algorithm,and I'm trying to avoid doing factoring at all costs, so that's why I started my question with a bunch of questions.  I thought that I might be able to just affix $\sqrt[3]{x}$ to a field and be done with it.  But it looks like I'm going to have to factor polynomials to get the field extensions that I'm after.

Comment: You still don’t say if $x$ is an element already in your field, or an indeterminate. So you may not be trying to be mysterious, but you insist on *just not answering that question about what $x$ is*, so you **are** being mysterious about it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about which "elements" you are adjoining to the field, think about what properties this new  element has. For example when take $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}[i]$ and construct the complex numbers we are adjoining a solution to the equation $x^2+1=0$. If there is no polynomial equation that puts the new element back into the old field then we get an infinite extension. For example $\mathbb{R}[x]$ gives us rational functions.

To get a finite new ring from a finite old ring we need to adjoin something that satisfies a polynomial relation putting it back into the old ring. So for example given the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ we can easily test that the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ has no solutions ($1+1+1=1$, and $0+0+1=1$). Thus we can get a new field buy taking $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ where we simply dictate that the new element satisfies $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$.

It turns out there is a very simple way of determining the size of the new field given the size of the old field. If $d$ is the degree of the polynomial relation that $\alpha$ satisfies (where we take the smallest polynomial we can that gets back into the original field) then $$|\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]|=|\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}|^d$$
So to cube the size of the field, we need to find a cubic equation that no existing elements satisfy, and adjoin a solution.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid factoring at almost all costs, so I asked this question to see if there is any way to add a field extension without doing the factoring.  It seems to me that I would have to factor, according to your question.  Is this correct?  One idea I had was to create the polynomial that has roots $r$ and proceed from there, so that instead of factoring, I just need to create the correct polynomial.  Could I do this?

Comment: @EnjoysMath: If you can find an element $a$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ that is not a cube, then the polynomial $x^3-a$ is irreducible and that will do. So you would “just” need to figure out what elements are not cubes.

Comment: @EnjoysMath (But that will only work if $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, as otherwise, every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a cube.)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I think I got what I need now.  Thanks for your persistence, and I am sorry that I gave poor explanations. You helped me a lot!!!